# How to use regex in lxml.html xpath?

Tags: python-3.x, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, lxml

I am trying to select a specific element with @id that can be any non-negative integer. So I try to use regex it looks like that:

```
response = get(url)
HTML_str = response.content
parser = html.fromstring(HTML_str)
search_string = r'./td[2]/span[re:match(id(), "^\d+$")]/text()'
l_spans_tags = parser.xpath(search_string, namespaces={'re': 'http://exslt.org/regular-expressions'})
```

However, the result is:

```
XPathEvalError: Invalid number of arguments
```

I understand that probably this approach is good for XML files, and not HTML files (also by using etree object - which was not used here). Can somebody point out how you can use regex on HTML files using lxml?

EDIT: 
What I needed is not the attribute id, but the attribute class. For finding tags as: 
`<span class="158">` or `<span class="19">`

Comment: What is `id()` supposed to do? There is an `id` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-id in XPath 1 but it requires an argument. So perhaps you get that error because of that `id()` function call. If you want to select an `id` attribute use `@id`.

Comment: You don't need to do regex matching and use extension functions in order to verify if a value is an integer. This can be done in pure XPath 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is not caused by your use of the "extension" function `re:match` to use regular expressions but rather by your use of the expression `id()` as that is a call to the XPath 1 function named `id` and that expects an argument: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#function-id while you haven't provided one.

I am not exactly sure what you want to use, perhaps you want to select the `id` attribute of the selected `span` element, that would work with `@id` e.g. `span[re:match(@id, "^\d+$")]`.

Based on your comment you want to check the value of an attribute node against a regular expression, so you just need to be aware that an attribute node named `id` in XPath is selected by `@id` and not by your attempt `id()` or that an attribute node named `class` is selected by `@class` and not by your attempt `@class()` you have shown in the comment.

In summary, both the error in your original question as well as the one from the code in the comment are not related to the attempt to use the extension function `re:match` but are simply caused by the wrong syntax to select an attribute node: use e.g. `@id` or `@class` to do that.

Comment: I do not understand your answer, I do try to get tags as <span class="158"> or <span class="19">. I changed to: search_string = r'./td[2]/span[re:match(@class(), "^\d+$")]/text()',  However then I get the following error: XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: Not sure where you learned your XPath basics but an attribute node named `class` is selected by `@class` and not by `@class()` so you simply want `span[re:match(@class, "^\d+$")]/text()`. All the errors you get are not related to the attempt to call an extension function but are simply caused by the wrong syntax to select attributes.

Comment: OK, thank you very much it is clear now. I had followed some misleading post... Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to detect a specific tag with @id that can be any integer.

*Any* integer? Even a *negative* one?

> `search_string = r'./td[2]/span[re:match(id(), "^\d+$")]/text()'`

Seems incorrect to try to select an attribute using a function (`id()` in this case)

To select `someAttribute` of an element that is the context (current) node, use:

```
@someAttribute
```

You also want to assert that the value of this attribute is an integer. This can be done in pure XPath 1.0 without using any extension function. The below XPath expression evaluates to `true()` exactly when the value of `$m` is an integer:

```
$m = floor($m)
```

**So, these combined and used to replace the predicate in your original expression** give us:

`search_string = r'./td[2]/span[@id = floor(@id)]/text()'`

And, in case the `id` must be a non-negative integer (as the provided regex implies), then use:

`search_string = r'./td[2]/span[@id >= 0 and @id = floor(@id)]/text()'`

Using these expressions results in more portable and likely more efficient code.

---

**Update**: The OP updated the question saying that he needs to select based on the value of the `class` attribute rather than on the `id` attribute.

In this case the above two expressions will be changed to these:

`search_string = r'./td[2]/span[@class = floor(@class )]/text()'`

and

`search_string = r'./td[2]/span[@class >= 0 and @class = floor(@class )]/text()'`